# How to throw meaningful data in exceptions?

Tags: c++, exception

I would like to throw exceptions with meaningful explanation (socket handle, process id, network interface index, ...) !
I thought of using variable arguments worked fine but lately I figured out it's impossible to extend the class in order to implement other exception types. So I figured out using an std::ostreamstring as a an internal buffer to deal with formatting ... but doesn't compile!
I guess it has something to deal with copy constructors. 
Anyhow here is my piece of code:

```
  class Exception: public std::exception {
public:
  Exception(const char *fmt, ...);
  Exception(const char *fname,
            const char *funcname, int line, const char *fmt, ...);
  //std::ostringstream &Get() { return os_ ; }
  ~Exception() throw();
  virtual const char *what() const throw();
```

protected:
  char err_msg_[ERRBUFSIZ];
  //std::ostringstream os_;
};

The variable argumens constructor can't be inherited from! this is why I thought of std::ostringstream!
Any advice on how to implement such approach ?

Comment: Define meaningful explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit awkward to pass `...` arguments, but possible. You need first to convert them to `va_list`. So, for your derived class to be able to pass the format and the arguments to its base class something like the following can be done:

```
class Exception: public std::exception {
public:
  Exception(const char *fmt, ...)
  {
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    this->init(fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
  }

  virtual const char *what() const throw();

protected:
  Exception(); // for use from derived class's ctor

  void init(char const* fmt, va_list, ap)
  {
    vsnprintf(err_msg_, sizeof err_msg_, fmt, ap);
  }

  char err_msg_[ERRBUFSIZ];
};

struct Exception2 : Exception
{
  Exception2(const char *fmt, ...)
  {
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    this->init(fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
  }
};
```

Comment: Yes I've been using the same approach but it reveals to be somehow painful to derive and implement :)

Answer (score 2):

I presume you mean the problem is that `ostringstream` isn't copy constructible.
If I understand correctly,
how about making `ostringstream` member be a pointer like `std/boost::shared_ptr`?
For example:

```
#include <exception>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>

struct E : std::exception {
  boost::shared_ptr< std::ostringstream > os_;
  mutable std::string s_;
  std::ostringstream &Get() { return *os_; } 
  const char *what() const throw() {
    s_ = os_->str();
    return s_.c_str();
  }
  E() : os_( boost::make_shared< std::ostringstream >() ) {}
  ~E() throw() {}
};

int main()
{
  try {
    E e;
    e.Get() << "x";
    throw e;
  }
  catch ( std::exception const& e ) {
    cout<< e.what() <<endl;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, the best solution is to define dedicated exception types for different exceptions. Your `SocketException` type would accept a socket handle, etcetera.  This eliminates the need for a vararg `...` argument in the ctor.

Also, you wouldn't need a `std::ostringstream os_` member. An `ostringstream` object is commonly used to format text, but not to store the result. For that purpose, use an ordinary `std::string`.